# Get Room object via companion using reflection and class name

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, singleton, android-room

As the title stands, I want to get a singleton instance via reflection using the class name. Let's say I have this class:

```
abstract class MyRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() { 

    abstract fun exampleEntityDao() : ExampleEntityDao

    companion object { 

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MyClass? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): MyClass {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, MyRoomDatabase::class.java, "db").build()

                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, knowing the class name `val strClass = MyRoomDatabase::class.qualifiedName.toString()`

I would like to achieve:
`MyRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this).getExampleEntityDao().doSomeStuff()` but via reflection.

I tried this:

```
val strClass = MyRoomDatabase::class.qualifiedName.toString()
val classFromStr = Class.forName(strClass)
val companion = classFromStr::class.companionObject
```

in that case, `companion` is null.

In the other case this: `val companion = MyRoomDatabase::class.companionObject` gives me the actual companion but I cannot do that because in the place where it should be done the compiler does know only the class name.

Comment: Does it work if you use `val classFromStr = Class.forName(strClass).kotlin`?

Comment: @iForests  it doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

`classFromStr::class` will return the class of `classFromStr` which is `Class` and doesn't have a companion object.

```
val companion = classFromStr.kotlin.companionObject
```

should work.